# Form controls are black during restore from FormWindowState.Minimized

Tags: vb.net, forms, controls, minimized

It doesn't stay in this state too long, but the user will see it if paying attention to the monitor. It looks horrible, is there anything I can do to stop this? I've included a screenshot of the form being restored.
[image: Image of restore]

Thank you

Comment: That means that the for and/or its controls are not being repainted in a timely manner, so you need to determine why that would be. Do you have any complex code being executed on the Paint event of the form? Is there any especially long-running code executed on the UI at any time.

Comment: Try: 1. Reduce execution time. 2. Set `DoubleBuffered = True` on all controls.

Comment: @jmcilhinney. You've pointed me in the right direction, thank you so much. I created a new form with a few controls and was able to reproduce the black controls when I added the code that set DoubleBuffered to true.